# Spinner onItemSelected not triggering

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

im trying to make an app for a university project with a very tight timeframe (So apologies for messy code) one of the features on this specific activity is when the user selects an id from a spinner the document will be loaded onto the screen for them to view. However the spinner is not recognising the onItemSelected method and nothing is being ran, the Log.d isnt being flared either so the method isnt being launched. No crashes.

```
public class Manage extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    ...
    ...

    //The following class is initiating the on item selected viewer for the navigation bar to use to read inputs.
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                //If "Request" is clicked, opens the request activity.
                case R.id.navigation_Request:
                    Intent requestIntent = new Intent(Manage.this, Request.class);
                    Manage.this.startActivity(requestIntent);
                    return true;
                //If "Search" is clicked, opens the search activity.
                case R.id.navigation_Search:
                    Intent searchIntent = new Intent(Manage.this, Search.class);
                    Manage.this.startActivity(searchIntent);
                    return true;
                //if "Manage" is clicked, do nothing, as the manage activity is already open.
                case R.id.navigation_Manage:
                    return true;
                //If "Premium" is clicked, opens the Premium activity.
                case R.id.navigation_Premium:
                    Intent premiumIntent = new Intent(Manage.this, Premium.class);
                    Manage.this.startActivity(premiumIntent);
                    return true;
                //If "Quit" is clicked, opens an alert box to ask if the user is sure they wish to quit
                //If "Yes" is clicked, the app closes. If "No" is clicked, the alert box closes.
                case R.id.navigation_Quit:
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Manage.this)
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you wish to quit?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    moveTaskToBack(true);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                            .show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    //When the activity is opened,the navigation bar is initiated, and its population is called.
    //The "Manage" part of the navigation bar is also set to be highlighted, as this is the users current activity.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manage);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_Manage);

        cloudstorage = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        spnTrades = findViewById(R.id.spnType);
        editDesc = findViewById(R.id.editDesc);
        editLocation = findViewById(R.id.editLocation);
        editPhone = findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        quoteImageButton = findViewById(R.id.imgQuote2);
        quotelist = findViewById(R.id.spnQuoteList);

        populatespinnerarray();
        populatespinner();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected item recognised");
        String selectedquote = quotelist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
            cloudstorage.collection("quotes")
                    .whereEqualTo("PhotoID", selectedquote)
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                                        descfinal = document.getString("Description");
                                        typefinal = document.getString("Trade");
                                        phonefinal = document.getString("Phone");
                                        locationfinal = document.getString("Location");
                                        loadquoteinfo();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Nope.");

            }






    public void populatespinnerarray() {
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String uid = user.getUid();
        cloudstorage.collection("quotes")
                .whereEqualTo("UserID", uid )
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                if (document != null && document.exists()) {
                                    queryid = document.getString("PhotoID");
                                    quoteArray.add(queryid);
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Line" +queryid+"added");
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error populating spinner: ", task.getException());


                        }

                    }
                });

      }
    public void populatespinner() {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Manage.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, quoteArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        quotelist.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void loadquoteinfo() {
        editDesc.setText(descfinal);
        editPhone.setText(phonefinal);
        editLocation.setText(locationfinal);

        if (typefinal == "Auto-Mechanic") {
            tradefinalpos = 1;
            spnTrades.setSelection(1);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Roof Repair") {
            tradefinalpos = 2;
            spnTrades.setSelection(2);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Carpentry") {
            tradefinalpos = 3;
            spnTrades.setSelection(3);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Landscaping") {
            tradefinalpos = 4;
            spnTrades.setSelection(4);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Decorating") {
            tradefinalpos = 5;
            spnTrades.setSelection(5);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Plumbing") {
            tradefinalpos = 6;
            spnTrades.setSelection(6);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Electrical") {
            tradefinalpos = 7;
            spnTrades.setSelection(7);
        }
        else if (typefinal == "Odd Jobs") {
            tradefinalpos = 8;
            spnTrades.setSelection(8);
        }





    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` at the end of the `populatespinner()` method, where **"spinner"** is the spinner you want to set the listener on.

This tells the spinner to use the listener you created.

Comment: No difference, unfortunately. 

D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5385660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe5383ee0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5385660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe5383ee0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5385660: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe5383ee0)

This is all i get in response